# How to have Apache's rewrite pattern match only urls in Folder?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to have a rewrite rule which will route a Request from `mywebsite/API/foobar.csv` to `mywebsite/API/data.php?code=foobar` where foobar is a user entered code, and will be come a Get Parameter for the data.php.

For this, I'm using the following  code in the `.htaccess` in the `API` folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ([^.]+)\.csv  data.php?code=$1  [L,NC,QSA]
```

This is working as expected, but it is also routing additional urls, such as:

```
 mywebsite/API/products/foobar.csv
 mywebsite/API/getProducts.php?code=foobar.csv
```

How do I write this rule, so that only when a request is made for a csv in this folder, will it get routed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I write this rule, so that only when a request is made for a csv in this folder

Tweak your regex like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)\.csv$ data.php?code=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Now it won't match `products/foobar.csv` since `/` is not allowed in captured part.

Comment: I had tried using `^`, but it was still selecting unnecessary urls, because I wasn't searching for words like in your regex. Thanks for your help.